# warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')

Tags: bash, curl, here-document, jenkins

I've read a lot here and then but still cannot find how to fix this:

```
steps.wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm']) {
    steps.withCredentials([steps.usernamePassword(credentialsId: "test", usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD')]) {
        steps.sh """                                                      
        curl  --silent -u \${GIT_USERNAME}:\${GIT_PASSWORD} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://some.url --data-binary @- <<-EOF
        {
        "state": "$STATE",
        "key": "\$JOB_NAME",
        "name": "\$BUILD_TAG",
        "url": "\$BUILD_URL",
        "description": "$DESCRIPTION"
        }
        EOF"""
```

This resides in jenkins shared library. I've read that I have to avoid whitespaces, but I don't see what whitespaces I've created here.
I keep receiving this error:

```
line 11: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
```

Comment: `steps.sh """ ` I'm pretty sure you need to use escape characters here, like: `steps.sh "\"" `

Comment: tripple quotes are for multiline support:https://www.programmersought.com/article/53312848028/ It is not a pure bash

Answer (score 5):

Apart from potentially creating invalid JSON unless you can assume that your variables are already JSON-encoded, you have an indentation issue with your here-document.

You are using `<<-EOF` to start the here-document containing your JSON document.  Such a here-document should be delimited by the string `EOF` and this string needs to be flush left (no indentation at all) *or* it may be indented using tab-characters (*not* spaces). There may be no whitespace or other characters of any kind on the same line *after* the `EOF` string.

My guess is that the code is indented using spaces, which is why the shell's parser can't find the terminating `EOF` string.

Comment: I've tried with tabs only but I still get it:     {
        "state": "$STATE",
        "key": "\$JOB_NAME",
        "name": "\$BUILD_TAG",
        "url": "\$BUILD_URL",
        "description": "$DESCRIPTION"
        }
        EOF

Comment: @WhoAmI I'm not familiar with Jenkins, so I don't know what transformations it applies to quoted strings before it's passed to a shell interpreter. (and judging from random forum posts I'm seeing, neither do people that actually use it)

Comment: @WhoAmI, please check if you have spaces, tabs or \r chars after the "EOF"

Comment: I changed my example and put the 3 double quotes immidiately after EOF to show that there are no whitespaces

Comment: @WhoAmI It still looks as if your editor i using multiples of four spaces for indentation, not spaces. As I also said, it's unclear what Jenkins does with the triple-double-quoted string before handing it over to a shell interpreter. You may want to try removing all indentation on the `EOF` line.